# IOS: store an array with NSUserDefault

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsarray, nsuserdefaults

I want to store an array with `NSUserDefault`, then, I put in `applicationDidEnterBackground`

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:myArray forKey:@"myArray"];
```

and in `application didFinishLaunchingWithOption`

```
myArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc] 
          initWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] 
           objectForKey:@"myArray"]];
```

it's ok for multitasking device, but for not-multitasking device, how can I solve?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Store the object in `NSUserDefaults` in `-applicationWillTerminate:`, if it hasn't already been saved by the invocation of `-applicationDidEnterBackground:` (i.e. check if multitasking is supported, if it is, then don't save it because it's already been saved.)

```
- (void) applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *) app {
    if([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(isMultitaskingSupported)] &&
       ![[UIDevice currentDevice] isMultitaskingSupported]) {
       [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:myArray forKey:@"myArray"];
    }
}
```

Comment: As pointed out in another answer, you need to synchronize the defaults after setting the object.  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

Answer (score 7):

Do not forget to sync the buffer before going into background:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Answer (score 3):

The previous answers are all correct, but note that neither `applicationDidEnterBackground` nor `applicationWillTerminate` are guaranteed to be called in all situations. You are usually better off storing important data whenever it has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Save NSUserDefaults at

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
```

Answer (score 0):

set

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:myArray forKey:@"myArray"];
```

in

```
applicationWillTerminate
```

Answer (score 0):

and don't forget to use the encodeWithCoder and initWithCoder inside the object that you are trying to save and that is contained in the array